# Exclui o repositório no Github Pages, recriei e o DNS não atualiza

Tags: github

Eu ouvi falar sobre o Github Pages e decidi verificar o serviço e adquiri um domínio. Não sou muito experiente, então fui seguindo passo-a-passo o que fazer. Fiz as configurações necessárias, criei o CNAME no repositório e confirmei as configurações no meu DNS Provider. Não funcionou. Percebi que meu CNAME estava com o domínio errado e alterei o arquivo para o nome correto, mas quando eu entrava no meu endereço (no caso, bonsaicc.github.io), ele continuou apontando para o endereço anterior.
Esperei algumas horas e exclui o repositório e recriei-o com o mesmo nome, com o CNAME correto. Entretanto, ele continua apontando para o endereço que eu escrevi errado.

Minhas questões são as seguintes:
1- É normal demorar tanto pra atualizar depois de alterar o CNAME?
2- Excluindo e recriando o repositório, eu posso ter cometido algum erro?

Obrigado!

**ATUALIZAÇAO**

Continuou a funcionar, não houveram problemas.